# FilterData Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to implement a filter system in my excel sheet.

However, I am hanging at displaying the data:

```
Sub FilterData()
    Sheets("App").Select
    Range("B12").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Clear

    Sheets("RawData").Range("Table1[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("RawData").Range("M1:P2"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("App").Range("B12"), Unique:=True
    Columns.AutoFit
    Range("B12").Select

End Sub
```

The function is take from:

[See Link!](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/11/27/extract-subset-of-data/)

The error looks like that:

[image]

Any suggestion what could be wrong? What could I check to get much deeper information?

I appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

Pls have a look at my named ranges:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
The error:

[image]

Comment: is `"Table1[#All]"` a named range? also I am not sure you can apply criteria like this `Sheets("RawData").Range("M1:P2")`

Comment: @mehow Thx for your answer! Please have a look at my update.

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this article](https://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/vbacode/debug.asp) will help you

Especially this part

> **Error Enabler**
>
> This section invokes the error handler:
>
> On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
>
> If an error occurs in the procedure, the code
>   jumps to the line where the label “PROC_ERR” is defined. For
>   consistency, use the same label name in every procedure.
>
> **Error Handler**
>
> This section is where the code goes if an error occurs in the
>   procedure:
>
> PROC_ERR:   MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description,
>   vbCritical
>
> Here you can manage the error and determine what to do
>   next. Examine the error object (Err) to see what occurred. For
>   instance, Err.Number is the error number, Err.Description is the error
>   description, etc.

If you add this to your code, you will able to see what type of error was happens.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I am getting `RunTime Error: 1004`. Any suggestions?

Comment: was there some `description`? or it's empty?

Comment: I think you need [this MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818808/en-us). Looks like your array contains too big string for copy to another list.

Comment: @MikkaRin I actually did it similar to him: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/11/27/extract-subset-of-data/

Comment: @Kare , Check my last comment. If your data contains long strings it might be a problem

Comment: Thx for your answer! Yep I understand, however I tried it even with his dataset and it does not work... btw my excel version 2010.